# Bot handoff to another bot

Tags: botframework

We use Azure Bot Framework as for our bot development activities in our organization. Multiple teams are involved in developing different domain specific bots. We have an ask where we have been required to develop an orchestrator bot that routes requests from the end-user to corresponding domain specific bots depending on the type of question raised by the user. The conversation should then continue with the domain specific bot once routed.

I've never handled such a scenario. I've heard about bot to agent hand-off but this seems to be different. I have no clue how to achieve this. Is this even possible? Any thoughts/ideas on this will be very helpful.

Comment: The question is closed so I can't post a full answer right now, but I think the Bot Framework "Skill" capability is what you're looking for - it provides the framework/samples for a "master" bot, that's able to call domain-specific sub Bots to deal with specific scenarios, using a Dispatch capability. Have a look at https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/overview/skills/ which talks about "his can be a complex Virtual Assistant or perhaps an Enterprise Bot seeking to stitch together multiple bots within an organization."

Comment: Here is the Enterprise Assistant starter: https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/solution-accelerators/assistants/enterprise-assistant/

Comment: Thanks Hilton. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: ok great, glad to help. I've sent a request to re-open the question, so I can post the answer properly and others can hopefully benefit